# Регулярное выражение, проверка tags

Tags: ruby

Сделал замену:
Не искало русские символы в тегах, сделал замену

```
-  advanced_filter(/^\@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)/) do |posts,match|
+  advanced_filter(/^\@([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_\-.]+)/) do |posts,match|
```

Выдает кучу ошибок. Прошу прощение, делаю по аналогии php

https://travis-ci.org/discourse/discourse/builds/236165023?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification

Comment: Непохоже, что падение вообще связано с вашим кодом.

Comment: Хм. Я еще в одном месте поменял. Но там аналогично:  

`- advanced_filter(/tags?:([a-zA-Z0-9,\-_]+)/) do |posts, match|

+  advanced_filter(/tags?:([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9,\-_]+)/) do |posts, match|`

Comment: Там [падение](https://travis-ci.org/discourse/discourse/jobs/236165025) такого характера, что у них билды на мастере вообще должны быть сломаны, в теории. Если `npm i -g eslint babel-eslint` упал у вас, непонятно, с чего бы ему выполняться вообще. Впрочем, чем чёрт не шутит -- попробуйте перезапустить упавшую задачу. Возможно, это был моментный фейл с сетью у самого трэвиса.

Comment: Дело в том, что вчера это было уже. А если попробовать конструкцию а-яА-Я заменить диапазоном, как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: Это не изменит статус на CI вообще никак :) Возможно, стоит поговорить об этом с мэйнтейнерами. А `а-яА-Я` никак в один диапазон не уместить, они в двух отдельных участках юникода. Улучшить это можно разве что добавив `ёЁ` (т. к. они в них не входят).